# Is it possible to set su to use WE password dialog

Tags: linux, gnome, su, pam, gnome-shell

I have sometimes problem when during entering password for su other window appears and steals the focus ("wait - did I just entered root password on public IRC chatroom?" - it did not happened but might).

Is it possible to configure su/sudo/PAM to use system dialog instead of terminal? I'm using gnome3/gnome-shell.

Comment: That feels like the wrong question: what matters isn't whether you type your password in the terminal window or a dedicated window, but whether focus stealing is prevented while you're typing your password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gksu` and `gksudo` in Gnome to have a password prompt window presented. I believe that under Gnome the gksu(do) prompt windows are protected from focus stealing.

You use gksu(do) in the same way you use su(do):

`gksudo apt-get update`

`gksu Bob`